# How to make dpkg faster?

Tags: debian, package-management, performance, dpkg

Package (un)installation on a Debian system is horribly slow, partly because it works with a whole bunch of (small) files. Short of getting faster storage, how do I speed it up? I'm thinking maybe loading some highly-accessed directory onto RAM as one solution, but how do I do that? Is there a 'better' solution?

Comment: What filesystem, and how many packages do you have? For large directories, ext3 or above with the `dir_index` option, or Reiser, is a dramatic improvement compared to ext2 or ext3 without `dir_index`.

Comment: @Gilles I use ext4 and have ~1400 packages installed.

Answer (score 22):

For this solution you are going to need a version of dpkg of at least 1.15.8.6.

Since that version of dpkg, there is a new `force-unsafe-io` option that will disable dpkg from calling sync() and the like between every package. You can add this option to the config in /etc/dpkg so that it is always in effect.

If you have an older version of dpkg you can alternatively use [eatmydata](http://www.flamingspork.com/projects/libeatmydata/).

And remember both of these solutions are unsafe and probably will lead to data loss if there is a power failure while or shortly after dpkg is running.

Comment: So, I just add `force-unsafe-io` to **/etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg**, and that's it?

Comment: I don't have a working linux box currently (PSU failure) but `echo "force-unsafe-io" > /etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg.d/force-unsafe-io` should work. Or you can add it to the main dpkg config file which I think is **/etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg**.

Comment: I timed it with and without this option, and there was **no** noticeable change in performance.

Comment: Did you try it with eatmydata? Additionally when I started using the force-unsafe-io option inside my pbuilder chroots, I remember a very noticeable difference.

Comment: http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=613428

Comment: @Arrowmaster: `/etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg.d/force-unsafe-io` is wrong. Config file should be one of these: `/etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg.d/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]*`, `/etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg`, `~/.dpkg.cfg` ([man dpkg.cfg](https://linux.die.net/man/5/dpkg.cfg)).

Comment: @pevik `/etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg.d/force-unsafe-io` matches the pattern which is the first entry in your list, so it *is* "one of these". Did you mean another pattern or is it a valid filename?