# Is there a faster alternative to pkg-config?

Tags: dynamic-linking, pkg-config

Our build system uses pkg-config to build the software, but the linking can take very long (sometimes up to 20 minutes). We identified pkg-config as the guilty tool.

So, is there a faster alternative to pkg-config? Or, are there some settings to use to speed up the linking?

PS I am not sure if [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7238/how-to-make-dpkg-faster) is relevant for this question.

Comment: Are you _certain_ pkg-config is the problem? That's just used to get build options (usually) which is orders of magnitude faster than actual linking (linking can be very expensive, especially with large-ish C++ code).

Comment: @Mat When I do top, I see pkg-config blocking the CPU. I also did `vmstat 1` and I see that both high disk access and high CPU usage. The code is large, but I don't think it should take 20 minutes to link an application. It is not that large. And I see it happening randomly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My colleague found [pykg-config](https://github.com/gbiggs/pykg-config/wiki), which proved to be much faster then pkg-config.

Answer (score 3):

Is `pkg-config` being invoked multiple times with the same options?  This could happen if you have an invocation of it embedded into a Makefile's `LDFLAGS` variable or similar.

With GNU Make, at least, if you call an external program via backticks, it is recalled every time it is referenced. E.g., in this instance, you'll get two different outputs:

```
foo = `date`
asdfsdf:
    echo $(foo)
    sleep 4
    echo $(foo)
```

However if you use the *shell* function, the result is evaluated only once:

```
foo = $(shell date)
asdfsdf:
    echo $(foo)
    sleep 4
    echo $(foo)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are other build tools such as [scons](http://www.scons.org/) and [cmake](http://www.cmake.org/) which maybe faster.

However, since your performance happens randomly, I would do more investigation before doing a large scale restructure of your build system.

Comment: But even for those, you have to somehow pass compiler/linker options. And for that you need pkg-config (unless you set them in your makefile, or whatever is used).

Comment: Have you tried running those pkg-config commands on their own, not as part of the build system?

Comment: They still block even if run on their own.

Comment: Have you tried to strace them to see where/why they block?